# Example of postgresql DISTINCT ON. Select one row of GROUP BY set based on condition on multiple columns

Tags: postgresql, select, group-by, distinct

I'd like to share an example of a very useful Postgres command: [Distinct On](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html).

I have data in the format below that comes from the USDA SSURGO Soil data set. For each mukey, I would like the cokey that has the highest comppct_r value among all values with majcomplfag = Yes, and if no cokey has majcomplfag = Yes, then I'd like the cokey with the largest comppct_r. If such a cokey is not unique, I'll take an arbitrary cokey among the optimal cokeys. A tiny sample of the data is below.

I started writing this up with some complicated clauses that still didn't cover all the possibilities, and then I discovered the incredibly simple and effective command **Distinct On**.

Distinct On groups by a field, then orders entries of the group according to criteria and selects the first. So, in my case, this difficult query can be written very simply as:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (mukey) mukey,cokey,majcompflag,comppct_r
FROM component
ORDER BY mukey,majcompflag DESC,comppct_r DESC
```

| mukey | cokey | majcompflag | comppct_r |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1020315 | 23068517 | No | 10 |
| 1020315 | 23068518 | No | 10 |
| 1020315 | 23068519 | No | 5 |
| 1020315 | 23068520 | Yes | 70 |
| 1020315 | 23068521 | No | 2 |
| 1020315 | 23068522 | No | 3 |
| 1020316 | 23068807 | No | 3 |
| 1020316 | 23068808 | No | 5 |
| 1020316 | 23068809 | No | 2 |
| 1020316 | 23068810 | No | 6 |
| 1020316 | 23068811 | No | 3 |
| 1020316 | 23068812 | No | 6 |
| 1020316 | 23068813 | Yes | 75 |

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a question. If you could rewrite that into a question that you answer yourself, it would be acceptable.

Comment: This is fine if majcompflag can only be 'Yes' or 'No'.  If there are other possibilities (like NULL) you would want to force all the non-'Yes' values to be tied.  Something like `ORDER BY mukey, majcompflag is distinct from 'Yes', comppct_r DESC`

Answer (score -1):

By using the DISTINCT ON, you can retrieve the cokey with the highest comppct_r among each group of mukey.
Try this code. This query will choose the row with the highest comppct_r value among the rows where majcompflag = Yes for each mukey. The row with the greatest comppct_r among the rows with majcompflag = No will be chosen if there are no rows with majcompflag = Yes for a specific mukey. If more than one row contains the same comppct_r value, DISTINCT ON will pick a random row.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (mukey) mukey, cokey, majcompflag, comppct_r
FROM component
WHERE majcompflag = 'Yes' OR (
  majcompflag = 'No' AND comppct_r = (
    SELECT MAX(comppct_r) FROM component c
    WHERE c.mukey = component.mukey AND majcompflag = 'No'
  )
)
ORDER BY mukey, majcompflag DESC, comppct_r DESC;
```

Hope it works :)